# How can I design in sketch for multiple sizes without exporting blurry versions?

Tags: export, sketch-app, artboard, multiple-sizes

I'm creating a visual version in Sketch of the to-be-designed website for a client. I'm working on a mobile version first. But he has an iPhone 5S with a 1136x640 resolution, while I have an 6+ with 2208x1242 resolution.

For best viewing purposes, I'm creating the visuals for his iPhone 5S resolution, but I want to view them on my iPhone too. However, exporting at @1x (regular 5S) and @1.94x (6+) makes great visuals for the 5S, but at some parts very blurry lines on my 6+ version.

Is there a way to design with sketch for multiple screen sizes with a single artboard without having separate versions become blurry?

<sup>*Of course, only for screen sizes with equal ratios (i.e. 16/9)*</sup>

Comment: Guess it's not possible since there are no half pixels or 3/4th pixels and the iPhone 6(+) resolution is in no way a multiplication of any other resolution

Comment: If you want to easily export a mockup for ios devices I would take a look at this Photoshop action http://appicontemplate.com/iphonescreenshot